# PHP date() formatting

Tags: php

I'm trying to format my date like YYYY-MM-DD.

I'm doing this:

```
 $dateAdded = date(Y-m-d);
```

So for today, it should say 2011-05-07, but it keeps returning 0000-00-00. Any help?

Comment: Check the warnings on your **error log**. This should be obvious when you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dateAdded = date("Y-m-d");
```

Its string, you forgot the ".

Answer (score 3):

You should use quotes because **Y-m-d** is a string:

```
$dateAdded = date("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dateAdded = date("Y-m-d");
```

The `date` function requires a string formatter. (Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more formatting constants.)

You can also use an optional timestamp if you want to format a date that is not `mktime()`:

```
$dateAdded = date("Y-m-d", $myTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the date format string..

```
$dateAdded = date('Y-m-d');
```